# How do I convert a asynchronous design pattern to a synchronous one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a script that gets the account value from my stock trading, which looks like this (working):

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
def account_summary_handler(msg):
    print(msg.tag, msg.value, msg.currency)
    connection.cancelAccountSummary(1)
    connection.disconnect()

connection = ibConnection(port=7497, clientId=100)
connection.register(account_summary_handler, 'AccountSummary')
connection.connect()
connection.reqAccountSummary(1, 'All', 'NetLiquidation')
```

It's a realtime API, so once the connection is open, updates are streaming, and `my_account_handler` gets called on every update.

I want to get the account balance from another synchronous script, something like, called something like:

```
myaccount.account_summary()
```

I've written something that looks like this (untested):

```
class IBAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clientId=100
        self.port=7497

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = ibConnection(port=self.port, clientId=self.clientId)

    def account_summary(self):
        self.connection.register(self.account_summary_handler, 'AccountSummary')
        connection.connect()
        connection.reqAccountSummary(1, 'All', 'NetLiquidation')

    def account_summary_handler(self, msg):
        self.connection.cancelAccountSummary(1)
        self.connection.disconnect()
        return msg.value
```

I believe I need account_summary() to block, and return the actual account value, rather than have it come back through a different function.

My question is:
**How do I get account_summary() to return the account value?**

In addition, if I'm using an inappropriate design pattern for this code and shouldn't use a class, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make it stated:

from ib.opt import ibConnection, message

```
class IBstate(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.clientId=100
        self.port=7496
        self.netLiquidation = None

        self.connection = ibConnection(port=self.port, clientId=self.clientId)
        self.connection.connect()
        self.connection.register(self.account_summary_handler, 'AccountSummary')
        self.connection.reqAccountSummary(1, 'All', 'NetLiquidation')    

    def account_summary_handler(self, msg):
        self.netLiquidation = msg
```

This runs in the background and updates the variables on the object as they change on the remote end.